# How to Zip a file/folder from QTreeView - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I get the file path from **self.fileSystemModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()**
deleting the filepath works, but zipping it doesn't... I have tried the zip code alone and it works.

The path provided by the **self.fileSystemModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()** cant be zipped...how can I get a path from the QTreeView that can be zipped

here is my code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os.path import basename
import zipfile


import DiskCleaner_ui


class main(QMainWindow, DiskCleaner_ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.openMenu()

        systray_icon = QIcon("s.png")
        self.systray = QSystemTrayIcon(systray_icon, self)
        self.systray.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.systray.show()
        self.systray.showMessage("DC", "Started...", QSystemTrayIcon.Information)
        # self.closeapp.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.Duplicate()
        self.Unused()
        self.Temp()



    def openMenu(self):
        self.menu = QMenu()
        self.restore = QAction("Restore", self)
        self.closeapp = QAction("Close", self)

        self.menu.addActions([self.restore, self.closeapp])


    def on_clicked(self, index):
        self.path = self.fileSystemModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        print(self.path)
        self.temp_delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_file)
        self.duplicate_delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_file)
        self.unused_delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_file)

        self.temp_zip_button.clicked.connect(self.zip_file)



    def zip_file(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.path):
            with ZipFile('C:\Windows\DC\zipfile.zip', 'w') as zip:
                zip.write(self.path, basename(self.path))

            print('file zipped successfully!')
        else:
            zf = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\Windows\DC\zipfile.zip', "w")
            for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(self.path):
                zf.write(dirname, basename(dirname))
                for filename in files:
                    zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename), basename(os.path.join(dirname, filename)))
            zf.close()
            print('All files/folders zipped successfully!')




    def delete_file(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.path):
            os.remove(self.path)
            self.systray.showMessage("DC", "Temporary file/folder Deleted", QSystemTrayIcon.Information)
            print('FIle Deleted...')
        else:
            pass




    def Temp(self):

        treeView = QTreeView()
        fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel(treeView)
        fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(False)
        root = fileSystemModel.setRootPath(r'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop\Py1')
        treeView.setModel(fileSystemModel)
        treeView.setRootIndex(root)
        treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        treeView.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        clearAll_button = QPushButton("Clear all Files")
        clearAll_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)
        self.temp_delete_button = QPushButton('Delete')
        self.temp_delete_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)
        self.temp_zip_button = QPushButton('Zip file')
        self.temp_zip_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)

        Layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        Layout.addWidget(clearAll_button)
        Layout.addWidget(self.temp_delete_button)
        Layout.addWidget(self.temp_zip_button)
        Layout.addWidget(treeView)


        self.Temp_Tab.setLayout(Layout)

    def Duplicate(self):

        treeView = QTreeView()
        self.fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel(treeView)
        self.fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(False)
        root = self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath(r'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop\Py2')
        treeView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)
        treeView.setRootIndex(root)
        treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        treeView.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        clearAll_button = QPushButton("Clear all Files")
        clearAll_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)
        self.duplicate_delete_button = QPushButton('Delete')
        self.duplicate_delete_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)
        zip_button = QPushButton('Zip file')
        zip_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)

        Layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        Layout.addWidget(clearAll_button)
        Layout.addWidget(self.duplicate_delete_button)
        Layout.addWidget(zip_button)
        Layout.addWidget(treeView)

        self.Duplicate_Tab.setLayout(Layout)

    def Unused(self):

        treeView = QTreeView()
        fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel(treeView)
        fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(False)
        root = fileSystemModel.setRootPath(r'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop\Py3')
        treeView.setModel(fileSystemModel)
        treeView.setRootIndex(root)
        treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        treeView.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        clearAll_button = QPushButton("Clear all Files")
        clearAll_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)
        self.unused_delete_button = QPushButton('Delete')
        self.unused_delete_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)
        zip_button = QPushButton('Zip file')
        zip_button.setFixedSize(90, 30)

        Layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        Layout.addWidget(clearAll_button)
        Layout.addWidget(self.unused_delete_button)
        Layout.addWidget(zip_button)
        Layout.addWidget(treeView)


        self.UnUsed_Tab.setLayout(Layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    H = main()
    H.show()
    app.exec_()
```

i get this error... [image]

> Error C:/Users/Black Laptop/Desktop/Py1/1 - Copy (7).txt Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File "test2.py", line 107, in zip_file with
>   ZipFile(dpath, 'w') as zip: \n File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init __ self.fp =
>   io.open(file, filemode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop

Comment: If the problem is not caused by the IDE then avoid using it, clearly the error is not generated by pycharm.

Comment: its from the code bro...the **self,path** can be deleted but cant be zipped - thats my problem

Comment: Have you understood what I have told you? The question and answers should not only serve you, but the entire community, and the main means to search are the tags, choose them wisely. As you ask for help, we ask you for consideration.

Comment: yea now i get...thanks....can u help

Comment: @X-Black... 
Do not run it with your IDE, open a CMD and execute it there.

Comment: @PRMoureu  everything works fine but the error comes up when i try to zip a file from the TreeView

Comment: then check the "Run" tab in Pycharm, or the cmd shell, you should have some traceback

Comment: @eyllanesc tried it same error...

Comment: @X-Black... 
I did not say that I was going to solve the problem but that there you would see the error message, you can show the error message that is printed in the CMD.

Comment: **Error**
C:/Users/Black Laptop/Desktop/Py1/1 - Copy (7).txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 107, in zip_file
    with ZipFile(dpath, 'w') as zip:
 \n File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init
__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Black Laptop\\Desktop

Comment: you are trying to compress files that do not have permissions.

Comment: @eyllanesc i got it ...Thanks....the actual error was from the code...my dpath didn't specify a zip file.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dpath error...change to a user directory...new code

```
def zip_file(self,):
    dpath = r'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop\DC.zip'
    if os.path.isfile(self.path):
        with ZipFile(dpath, 'w') as zip:
            zip.write(self.path, basename(self.path))

        print('file zipped successfully!')
    else:
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(dpath, "w", )
        for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(self.path):
            zf.write(dirname, basename(dirname))
            for filename in files:
                zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename), basename(os.path.join(dirname, filename)))
        zf.close()
        print('All files/folders zipped successfully!')
```